# Contains references to both AndroidX and old support library

Tags: android, ios, flutter, androidx, android-jetifier

After upgrating flutter version to **Flutter 1.22.0-2.0.pre.78 • channel master** I am getting this warning:-

> WARNING:
> [Processor] Library
> 'C:\Users....gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\flutter_embedding_debug\1.0.0-b1d9f863db32cb1d6714cf75db4a992ee3765113\b8748b5192a2a0961f5c14f8845331ad5f2225a1\flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b1d9f863db32cb1d6714cf75db4a992ee3765113.jar'
> contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This
> seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to
> rewrite the library anyway.  Example of androidX reference:
> 'androidx/annotation/VisibleForTesting'  Example of support library
> reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'`

Is this issue will cause some serious issue in future or not. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Hi any news on that

Answer (score 8):

This warning exist because on the [latest Flutter versions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases) newly created projects will be created with [AndroidX automatically](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-know-if-my-project-is-using-androidx).

> Starting from Flutter v1.12.13, new projects created with `flutter create -t <project-type>` use AndroidX by default.
>
> Projects created prior to this Flutter version must not depend on any
> [old build
> artifact](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)
> or [old Support
> Library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings)
> class.
>
> In an app or module project, the file `android/gradle.properties` or
> `.android/gradle.properties` must contain:
>
> ```
> android.useAndroidX=true
> android.enableJetifier=true
> ```

The warning also stated:

```
This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
```

This is usually caused by some plugins that was not migrated and [Flutter tool uses Jetifier](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#what-if-my-app-is-migrated-to-androidx-but-not-all-of-the-plugins-i-use) which will automatically migrate those Flutter plugins using the Support Library to AndroidX.

> The Flutter tool uses Jetifier to automatically migrate Flutter
> plugins using the Support Library to AndroidX, so you can use the same
> plugins even if they haven’t been migrated to AndroidX yet.

You can [open an issue to GitHub](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#im-having-issues-migrating-to-androidx) if you've encounter other issues when migrating to AndroidX.

Comment: thank you for useful answer